# Reading lines in a file that end with \n

Tags: python, file, io, newline

When I do

```
f = open("test.txt","r")
s = f.readline()
l = s.split[' ']
```

in which the input file has the content `2 3\n`. `s` has the value `['2', '3\n']`. Is there a way to tell python that each line ends with a `\n` and therefore it should not read it?

Contents of file:

```
3 2\n
#1###2#\n
****#**\n
##*###*\n
#******\n
#*#O##*\n
```

I will do other operations for the other lines. But I still need to get rid of `\n`

Comment: `l = s.strip().split()` ?  `strip()` will remove the new-line char

Comment: You can `strip` characters from strings

Comment: but the lines after it have characters and again end with `\n`. For instance `#@1\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caveat here is that except for the literal `'\n'` there is also an actual `\n` at the end of each line (except for the last line, which only has the literal `'\n'`):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print(f.readlines())
# ['3 2\\n\n', '#1###2#\\n\n', '****#**\\n\n', '##*###*\\n\n', '#******\\n\n', '#*#O##*\\n']
```

You need to call `.strip` with both the literal `'\n'` and the actual `\n`:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip('\\n\n') for line in f]

print(lines)
# ['3 2', '#1###2#', '****#**', '##*###*', '#******', '#*#O##*']
```